# Be able to read TinyMCE Comments in readonly mode

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I am using TinyMCE with the Comment plugin. There is some functionality that changes the editor's mode to 'readonly'. While TinyMCE is readonly, I want users to be able to see the highlights and click on them to read the comments. This seems so far impossible to achieve.

Comment: Here is a codepen with a comment and button to disable TinyMCE https://codepen.io/ahuqwe/pen/rNqXVyQ

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with TinyMCE and our commercial comments plugin today as once you place the editor in read only mode the UI of TinyMCE is not functional.

If you wish to request this as a Feature Request we recommend opening a support ticket and making that request.